# Ansible URI module ignore body for GET request

Tags: ansible, uri

why URI module ignores body. I need to send body to get the response what I need. Python request module works fine.

```
---

- name: Get info 
  hosts: local_host
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    auth_key: 'xxxxxx'

  tasks:
    - name: Fetch all entries matching
      uri: 
        url: "https://get_changes.com?"
        method: GET
        headers:
             Content-Type: "application/json"
             Accept: "application/json"
             Authorization: 'Basic {{auth_key}}'
             Timeout: '30'
        body_format: json
        body:
             sysparm_fields: "number, state"
sysparm_query:"cur_state=10^number=abcdef^u_ci_infra_type=network^name=Network"
        return_content: yes
        status_code: 200
      register: crb_output
```

Comment: Are you able to share the working example using python requests? It will be easier to compare

Comment: I was about to share python code. Question is,  does URI support body. I haven't seen any examples online. If you have please share.

Comment: Sorry I meant does URI supports body in GET request ?. I see everyone used body in POST request only.

Comment: I think you answered your question by yourself.
Ansibles URI module oviously doesn't support a body in the GET Method which is by the way very unusual. It's more common to pack request parameters in the request URL instead of using a body.

Comment: Ah I see. That's true. Args should be in URL itself. forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see. That's true. Args should be in URL itself for GET. forgot about that. Thanks.